# Selecting column as unique value sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table in **MS SQL Server** "MyTable" like below -

```
PkId    |    Title   |   Some Column
-----------------------------------------------
1       |    User 2  | Some value for "User 2"
-----------------------------------------------
2       |    User    | Some value for the user
-----------------------------------------------
3       |    User    | Some value for the user
-----------------------------------------------
4       |    Admin   | Some value for the Admin
-----------------------------------------------
5       |    Guest 1 | Some value for "Guest 1"
-----------------------------------------------
6       |    Guest   | Some value for the guest
```

I want to have an output like -

```
User 1 - Some value for the user
User 2 - Some value for "User 2" [Note - this "User 2" title was existing and this keeps the "Some Column" value intact as well]
User 3 - Some value for the user
Admin 1 - Some value for the Admin
Guest 1 - Some value for "Guest 1" [Note - Existing title with existing value]
Guest 2 - Some value for the guest
```

[I don't care about the ordering, but want to map users like above so that I can get the numbers after title (if the title is already with the numbering it skips that one and don't duplicate the same) the "Some Column" value remains as is]

I have tried with rank over partition but did not achieve the expected result. Please help me here.

Comment: But why? An id is just an id, it's value doesn't matter.

Comment: Do you want to update Title column? Do Name column have duplicates?

Comment: You need to clarify this - you want to output what you have shown based on the 'first/second' in the name?

Comment: I don't care about the id. I just want to select the title column as "User 1, User 2, User 3". Note that "User 2" is already present in the title column. So, I can't just add row_number to the title.

Comment: It's generally a bad idea to store computed values (from other columns). Data inconsistency... Create a view instead. Or have a computed column.

Answer (score 1):

This query should do what you want. This is probably inneficient and as it has been said by others, this is probably a good idea to store user and numbers in a string like this.

**Query:**

```
With titles as (
    SELECT distinct title = title FROM @MyTable
    WHERE NOT RIGHT(title, 1) LIKE '[0-9]'
), numbers as (
    SELECT n = ROW_NUMBER() over(PARTITION BY t.title ORDER BY pkid DESC)
        , pkid
        , Name 
        , grp = t.title
        , id = TRY_PARSE(CASE WHEN d.title NOT LIKE t.title THEN RIGHT(d.title, ABS(LEN(d.title) - LEN(t.title))) END as bigint)
        , missing = ROW_NUMBER() over(PARTITION BY t.title, CASE WHEN d.title NOT LIKE t.title THEN 0 ELSE 1 END ORDER BY pkid DESC)
    FROM @MyTable d
    INNER JOIN titles t ON d.title LIKE t.title+'%'
), new_n as (
    SELECT n, grp, id = ROW_NUMBER() over(PARTITION BY grp ORDER BY n)
    FROM (
        SELECT n, grp
        FROM numbers
        EXCEPT
        SELECT id, grp
        FROM numbers
        WHERE id IS NOT NULL
    ) as x
)
SELECT nb.pkid, n = coalesce(nb.id, nw.n), nw.grp+CAST(coalesce(nb.id, nw.n) as varchar(5)), nb.name--, *
FROM numbers nb
LEFT JOIN new_n nw ON nb.grp = nw.grp AND nb.missing = nw.id
ORDER BY nb.pkid
```

- CTE `titles` looks for distinct titles without a number (user, admin and guest)
- CTE `number` partitions them by group title (n), gets the id for existing titles (id) and partition by group title and whether id is missing (missing)
- CTE new_n gets a list of unused id for each group
- Last select put everything together and use the existing id or replace it by 1 of the available id when it's missing

**Output:**

```
pkid    n   title   name
1       2   User2   Some value for "User 2"
2       3   User3   Some value for the user
3       1   User1   Some value for the user
4       1   Admin1  Some value for the Admin
5       1   Guest1  Some value for "Guest 1"
6       2   Guest2  Some value for the guest
```

**Data:**

```
declare @MyTable table(pkid int, title varchar(100), name varchar(100));
insert into @MyTable(pkid, title, name) values
    (1, 'User 2', 'Some value for "User 2"')
    , (2, 'User', 'Some value for the user')
    , (3, 'User', 'Some value for the user')
    , (4, 'Admin', 'Some value for the Admin')
    , (5, 'Guest 1', 'Some value for "Guest 1"')
    , (6, 'Guest', 'Some value for the guest')
    ;
```

Comment: It doesn't output what's expected.

Comment: Actually there can be entries for other values too in the title column. Like "Admin". In that case I need to select those as Admin 1, Admin 2 etc. That is why I used "Partition by title" with row_number. but that did not work.

Comment: @Giorgi Nakeuri cast is on the number. it should be enough in this sample and for numbers up to 99.999....

Answer (score 0):

use this :

```
select 'user ' + (case when patindex('%[0-9]%',title) = 0  then row_number() over (partition by title order by (select 1)) else substring(title,patindex('%[0-9]%',title),1) end) +  '-' + somecolumn
from table1
```

If the number is always at the end of the title column you can use -

```
select 'user ' + (case when isnumeric(right(title,1)) = 1 then right(title,1)  else  row_number() over (partition by title order by (select 1)) end) +  '-' + somecolumn
from table1
```

Comment: Sam, I have just put an example here. "First User" won't be the actual value over there. There can be any value. I put those values just to make people understand the mapping.

Comment: SQL does not have any row order until specified explicitly. So in your  example above what is the criteria to specify that first row that has user 2, second row has user 1 ...etc.I mean you have to tell SQL Server which row has what...?. For this you need another mapping in another table defining the same.